# How to Restrict date in jquery datetimepicker based on another datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I have two datetimePickers in the same page and I wanna change the second datetimepicker's minDate depending the first one. Here is my code:

```
  $(function() {
    if ($("#p-from").length > 0) {
        $('#p-from').datetimepicker();
    }

    if ($("#p-to").length > 0) {
        $('#p-to').datetimepicker();
    }

});
```

i am used

```
jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js
```

Comment: What datetimepicker are you using? Probably you added too many tags since you used both _datepicker_ and _datetimepicker_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/tSrGx/28/

```
 $(function () {
     $("#from").datepicker({

         changeMonth: true,
         numberOfMonths: 1,
         minDate: -0,
         onClose: function (selectedDate) {
             var date2 = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
             date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
             $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", date2);
         }
     });

     $("#to").datepicker({

         changeMonth: true,
         numberOfMonths: 1
     });
 });
```

Comment: i used datetimepicker not datepicker